# How can I decide if there should be subjunctive mood in an if-clause?

Tags: subjunctives

For example, there are two sentences:

> 1. If she lived in a mill town, the choice was more or less made for her.
> 2. If she lived in a mill town, the choice would be more or less made for her.

What the difference between them? And is it necessary to apply subjunctive mood in the first sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by subjunctive mood?

Comment: Subjunctive mood is a mood to express a request, suggestion or assumption in a modest way. E.g. If I were you, I wouldn't do things in that way.